# Printf call in assembly not formatting IEEE-754 floating point value as hex during output

Tags: c, assembly, printf, x86-64

Here is the string format I am trying to print:

values: "The harmonic sum of %ld terms is %1.18lf, which is 0x%016lx"

Here is the code in assembly:

```
mov qword   rax, 2
mov         rdi, values
mov         rsi, r15
call        printf
```

Basically it is outputting the first two values correctly, but the third prints as "0x0000000000000000" which is not correct. The thing is that if I change "%016lx" to something else like "%a" or %1.18lf" it appears to be receiving the correct value so I have no idea why the conversion isn't working for the "%lx" format in particular.

The lower half of xmm0 and xmm1 both contain the desired value I wish to print.

Comment: Are `long int`s passed in xmm1?

Comment: Have you considered compiling some C code that produces the right output, and disassembling it, to make sure your call is correct? The printf function is a varargs function, and there's loads of platform-specific weirdness in those...

Comment: `%lx` expects a long int, and as such the next integer register, `rdx` in your case.

Comment: hmm I was unaware that it automatically grabbed from rdx for that format. Thank your guys for the help

Comment: @Jester: Sure? I'd more expect variadic arguments to be passed on the stack. How else would they be easily iterable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%lx` reads a `long int`. Integer values are stored in the integer registers, which `xmm1` is not. The value should be stored in the next integer register (which is `rdx` according to Jester's comment).

Comment: Are you sure variadic arguments are passed in registers actually? Normally they are just passed on the stack to be easily iterable in the function or forwarded to a nested variadic function.

Comment: @Olaf I'm assuming they are since the OP is passing some in registers already and they work. I didn't actually look it up, so I could be wrong.

Comment: @Olaf, variadic functions are quite involved because they do in fact use registers and any spillage on the stack (64-bit code). The underlying code generated is quite involved. Section 3.5.7 (page 50) in the System V x86-64 ABI you'll find the methodology documented for dealing with variadic functions. http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf

Comment: @MichaelPetch: So it is like ARM, but xith tons of legacy stuff added. Makes somewhat sense for the caller, because it does not need to care if a function is variadic or not; just marshal the arguments the standard way. For the callee it becomes more difficult to iterate them, however. Not sure if that's worth the effort.